# C++ Read a text file to populate a 2D array

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to create a snake game in C++. The player is going to have a choice of levels when they start the game of varying difficulties. Each level is stored in a .txt file and I'm having issues populating the array from the file. Here's the code I have so far with regards to getting the array from the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("LevelEasy.txt");
    fin >> noskipws;

    char initialLevel[10][12];

    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 12; col++)
        {
            fin >> initialLevel[row][col];
            cout << initialLevel[row][col];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It populates the first line and prints it perfectly fine. The issue arises when it gets to the end of the line, which subsequently causes problems on every line afterwards. I expect it to print like so;

```
############
#          #
#          #
#          #
#          #
#          #
#          #
#          #
#          #
############
```

But it just ends up printing something like this;

```
############

#
#
#
 #
#
  #
#
   #
#
    #
#
     #
#
      #
#
       #
###
```

I'm just wondering how upon reaching the end of the line, I can stop adding to the line of the array and move to the next instead? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See πάντα ῥεῖ's answer below. In short: I consider it better to read lines of data and parse the strings if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would use to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("LevelEasy.txt");

    std::vector <std::string> initialLevel;
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(fin,line)) {
        initialLevel.push_back(line);
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be even shorter codes using [`std::back_inserter()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is there any way I could do this using a 2D array?

Comment: @Tom `std::vector <std::string>` already composes a 2D array. Stop using raw arrays and pointers in c++ please.

Comment: Aren't vectors different to arrays? Even though they function very similarly

Comment: @Tom No, they aren't different. At least not regarding access operations.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, this works perfectly in the full program

Comment: @Tom Under the hood there are things going on according memory management and such, but unless you're looking about micro optimisation you can just leave that behind.